# Incremental backup of an entire FTP server with Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, bash, ftp

I'm looking for a simple way to schedule full + incremental backup of a remote FTP server (that also supports SFTP, but without SSH access) from My NAS that is based on Linux, WITH full SSH access. I'm surprised by the fact that there are a lot of solutions, but many of them are quite "oversized" for a simple task like this (for example: Bacula).

The idea is to setup a full backup every week and the rest will be daily and incremental.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it will be better here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: veeam could do the job

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

- configure and use `rclone`
- use `lftp mirror`
- you can try mounting the remote server filesystem locally via `sshfs`, then using `rsync` to sync the required files (note: it will be less efficient than running `rsync` via an explicit network target, but the latter requires full SSH access).